# WiFi dongle works on raspberry pi 4 but when i put sd card and wifi dongle with PiZero it does not show up in ifconfig?

Tags: pi-4, pi-zero, driver

I am trying to plug a USB wifi adaptor to raspberry pi zero and I got driver problem so I removed the sd card and usb wifi  adaptor and put it on a raspberry pi 4  and installed the drivers and when I check on raspberry pi 4 driver works there is wlan0 and wlan1 in ifconfig.
But when I transfer the sd card and the wifi adaptor to the raspberry pi zero it does not show up.
It's not a USB to micro USB adaptor problem I check that it works...

**UPDATE** with info from a comment:
i installed a fresh copy of rasbian into sd card and installed 8188fu-4.19.118-v7l-1311 driver but still it does not see the wifi adaptor this is where I downloaded the driver [downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/8188fu-drivers](http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/8188fu-drivers/).

Comment: The drivers are kernel level specific.  It best to run the config utility from http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/install-wifi for it to check.  I take it you are putting it into the correct USB port?

Answer (score 1):

They have different drivers and hardware. Hence this updates won't work.
You have to install files for Zero only. RPi4 and Zero drivers will conflict with each other.

Comment: i installed a fresh copy of rasbian into sd card and installed 8188fu-4.19.118-v7l-1311 driver but still it does not see the wifi adaptor this is where I downloaded the driver http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/8188fu-drivers/